# Can't install Revel with go get

Tags: go

My `go env`:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/xamenrax/code/golang"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.3.2/libexec"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.3.2/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

But where I'm doing `go get github.com/robfig/revel` there is no any output, this command just silently do nothing.

Comment: use `-v`, always use `-v`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does nothing, but check the content of the `$GOPATH/src/github.com/robfig/revel` folder.

If that folder exists, chances are the `go get` did download, compile and install your project.

---

The workaround is to do it manually:

- create a `robfig` folder in `$GOPATH/src/github.com`, and
- in that `robfig` folder, try:

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/robfig/revel
  ```
- Then in the `revel` folder, try a `go build`, then `go install`

As [commented below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120448/cant-install-revel-with-go-get/26120544#comment40938241_26120544):

> `go build` command should be executed from `$GOPATH/src/github.com/robfig/revel/revel`

Comment: here is my ``ls`` output:

``code.google.com github.com``,

There is no Revel folder.

Comment: Can you try and create a `robfig` folder in `$GOPATH/src/github.com`, and in that `robfig` folder, try: `git clone https://github.com/robfig/revel`. Then in the `revel` folder, try a `go build`, then `go install`, just to see if the manual process work.

Comment: And it worked, thank you, but why It could be broken?

Comment: @Nikita not sure actually. I have included the workaround in the answer.

Comment: anyways ``revel help`` executed from $GOPATH directory returns ``zsh: command not found: revel``

Comment: @Nikita does your $PATH include $GOPATH/bin ?

Comment: Yup
``export GOPATH=/Users/xamenrax/code/golang export PATH="$PATH:$GOPATH/bin"`` in my ``.zshrc`` file

Comment: and $GOPATH/bin: is it empty?

Comment: So the go install didn't work then. Did you do a go install after the go build?

Comment: Yup, go build, then go install

Comment: @Nikita after the go build, do you see a binary in $GOPATH/src/github.com/robfig/revel ?

Comment: Well, it's my fault, the ``go build`` command should be executed from ``$GOPATH/src/github.com/robfig/revel/!revel!`` path. It's all ok now, thank you!

Comment: @Nikita Excellent. I have included that in the answer for more visibility.